# How to use sed to replace specific part of a string only?

Tags: bash, sed

```
echo "async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2" |
sed 's/\_(_scripts_artifact_)./\-(_scripts_artifact_).*/g'
```

output

```
async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2
```

expected output

```
async-task-payload-manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2
```

Answer (score 2):

All `_`s that occur before `_scripts_artifact` will be replaced by `-`s by this `sed` command:

```
echo "async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2" |
sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*\)_\(.*_scripts_artifact\)/\1-\2/; ta'
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_/\n/4g;y/_\n/-_/' file
```

Translate all `_`'s but the first 3 to newlines.

Translate all `_`'s to `-`'s and all newlines to `_`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue!

Perl has the **lookahead** assumption, i.e. you can say "replace _ followed by anything *and `payload_manager_scripts`* with a dash":

```bash
echo async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2 \
| perl -pe 's/_(?=.*manager_scripts_artifact)/-/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. This code uses `match` function of GNU `awk`. Which allows us to use regex(`(^.*)(_manager_scripts_artifact_.*)` in this case) and create capturing groups which are stored into array(arr in this case) values with index of `1,2,3....` and later on we are retrieving and substituting `_` with `-` in 1st part of array and then printing both elements of array to achieve the expected results.

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5u9mQd/1) for used regex to understand capturing groups getting created with it.

```bash
##Shell variable
val="async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2"

awk '
match($0,/(^.*)(_manager_scripts_artifact_.*)/,arr){
  gsub(/_/,"-",arr[1])
  print arr[1] arr[2]
}
' <<<"$val"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "async_task_payload_manager_scripts_artifact_1.0.0-2" > file

cat << EOF >> ed1
1s/payload_/payload_%/
wq
EOF

cat << EOF >> ed2
1s/_/-/g
1,2j
wq
EOF

ed -s file < ed1
cat file | tr '%' '\n' > file2
mv file2 file
ed -s file < ed2
rm -v ./ed1 ./ed2
```